# Error connecting to ... No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

Tags: identityserver4

I just got the latest IdentityServer4 and quickstart code and trying to follow the instruction of quickstart to set it up and test. And I am using VS.Net 2019 on my Windows 10 laptop. The setup process seemed to be fine and the code compiled with no issues. But when I run the Client project from VS, I got the error message "Error connecting to https://localhost:5001/.well-known/openid-configuration. No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.." at the following line of Client code:
var disco = await client.GetDiscoveryDocumentAsync("https://localhost:5001");
Can someone tell me what I might be missing here? By the way, localhost:5001 should be my identity server and I use https://localhost:6001 for my API.

Comment: It seems weird that you'd use "https" to connect to localhost.  Is that right?

Comment: I tried http as well but got the same result. I changed it back after that.

Comment: Hmm ok-- I would do a basic `telnet localhost 5001` to make sure that you have a server process listening on that port.  I'm not familiar with what you're doing but if you have a client connecting to localhost:5001, then you need to have a server process listening on that port

Comment: I can't. telnet connection failed. But what does that mean? The identity server is not running? I have followed every steps in the quickstart instructions.

Comment: Ya that probably means it's not running or it's running on a different port.  I'm not familiar with that technology but  you can list your running processes to see whether it's running.

Comment: Besides, when I browse https://localhost:5001/.well-known/openid-configuration in my Chorm, instead of getting a discovery document, I get a "site cannot be reached" and ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED error.

Comment: Ok well it seems like your server is either not running or it's running on a different port.  If you share the instructions you followed I can prob look through them

Comment: Thanks for your input! It turns out that my VS project IdentityServer failed starting because that VS "doesn't know how to start the project with IIS Express profile". When I switch from IIS Express to SelfHost, I am able to get connected. Know what I need to do is to figure out why my IIS Express profile doesn't work. Thanks again Howard_Roark! I would love to give you credit for the input but don't know how as you didn't put in an answer, but just comments. Can I mark a comment as answer? Please let me know.

Comment: Oh thanks, that is nice of you.  I'm glad you figured it out.  I can move my comment to an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per our discussion in the comments, a good first step is to run a `telnet` test:

```
telnet localhost 5001
```

The failed connection showed us that either your server was not running or it was listening on a different port.  Ultimately you were able to determine that it was not running, and you concluded that it did not start due to an issue with your IIS Express profile.